# using string, blob or clob for thread body in doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine

what data type (string, blob or clob) should i use for my thread body when using doctrine?

and what length should it be?

i have read the [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/pl/defining-models:columns:data-types) but dont quite understand the differences between them.

seems that all three can store unlimited nr of characters.

could someone explain

and how do i store unlimited characters in string? what should i set as length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer blob as datatype, to store unlimited text with all the richtext formating stuff.

Comment: Blobs aren't very queryable - make sure you don't want to do text searches before you commit to a non-text datatype.